# Troubles with slow speeds in opencl

Tags: c, gpu, opencl

I am trying to use opencl for the first time, the goal is to calculate the argmin of each row in an array. Since the operation on each row is independent of the others, I thought this would be easy to put on the graphics card.

I seem to get worse performance using this code than when i just run the code on the cpu with an outer forloop, any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```c
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable

int argmin(global double *array, int end)
{
  double minimum = array[0];
  int index;
  for (int j = 0; j < end; j++)
  {
    if (array[j] < minimum)
    {
      minimum = array[j];
      index = j;
    }
  }
  return index;
}

kernel void execute(global double *dist, global long *res, global double *min_dist)
{
  int row_size = 0;
  int i = get_global_id(0);

  int row_index = i * row_size;
  res[i] = argmin(&dist[row_index], row_size);
  min_dist[i] = dist[res[i] + row_index];

}
```

Comment: "I seem to get worse performance." Why don't add some info about execution times (and maybe your hardware)? And a "regular for loop" means the "same" implementation on the cpu just with an outer for loop instead of the threads on the gpu? Regarding the performance I would say the access pattern is really bad for a gpu. A column-major order would be better. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008125/which-memory-access-pattern-is-more-efficient-for-a-cached-gpu).

Comment: If your opencl device is a discrete GPU, then i'm not really surprising you get worse performance. Your kernel is trivial, and the total runtime is dominated by overhead of transferring data. CPU and iGPU would not need to transfer any data, but discrete GPU does, and transfers over PCIe are relatively slow. There's really no point running this code on discrete GPUs unless it's part of larger computation.

Comment: @Shadesfear Your function argmin() has a bug. If the first element is the minimum, then it returns an uninitialised integer. You should initialise it with zero. It probably would be zero, but you can't guarantee that.

Answer (score 1):

The commenters make some valid points, but I'll try to be a little more constructive and organised:

1. Your data appears to consist of `double` precision floating point values. Depending on your GPU, this can be bad news in itself. Consumer grade GPUs typically are not optimised for working with `double`s, often only achieving 1/32 or 1/16 the throughput compared to single-precision `float` operations. Many pro-grade GPUs (Quadro, Tesla, FirePro, some Radeon Pro cards) are fine with them though, achieving 1/2 or 1/4 throughput versus `float`. As you're only performing a trivial arithmetic operation (comparison), and there's a good chance your runtime is dominated by memory access, it could be fine on consumer hardware too.
2. I assume your `row_size` is not actually 0, it would help to know what the true (typical) value is, and whether it's fixed, variable by row, or variable per run but the same for each row. In any case, unless `row_size` is very small, the fact that you are running a serial `for` loop over it could be holding your code back.
3. How big is your work size? In other words, how many rows in your array (give a typical range if it varies)? If it is very small, you will see little benefit from GPU parallelism: GPUs have a large number of processors and can schedule a few threads per processor. So your work items will need to number hundreds or better thousands to achieve decent hardware utilisation.
4. You are reading a very large array from (presumably) system memory and not performing any intensive operations on it. This means your bottleneck will typically be on the memory access side - for discrete GPUs, system memory access needs to go through PCIe, so the speed of that link will place an upper bound on your performance. Additionally, your memory access pattern far from ideal for GPUs - you typically want work items to read adjacent memory cells at the same time as the memory unit typically fetches 64 bytes or more at once.

Improvement suggestions:

- Profiling. If at all possible, use your GPU vendor's profiling tools to determine your true bottlenecks. Otherwise we're just guessing.
- For (4) - if at all possible, try not to move large amounts of data around too much. If you can generate your input arrays on the GPU, do so, so they never leave VRAM.
- For (4) - Optimise your memory accesses. AMD, NVidia and Intel all have OpenCL GPU optimisation guides which explain how to do this. Essentially, re-structure your data layout, or your kernel such that adjacent work items read adjacent pieces of memory. You ideally want work item 0 to read array item 0, work item 1 to read array item 1, etc. You may need to use local memory to coordinate between work items. Another option is to read vector-sized chunks of data per work item. (e.g. each work-item reads a double8 at a time) Watch for alignment in this case though.
- For (2) & (3) - Unless `row_size` is very small (and fixed), try to split your loop across multiple work items and coordinate using local memory (reduction algorithms) and atomic operations in global memory.
- For (1): If you've optimised everything else and profiling is telling you that comparing `double`s on consumer hardware is too slow, either check if you can generate the data as `float`s without loss of accuracy (this will also halve your memory bandwidth woes), or check if you can otherwise do better somehow, for example by treating the `double` as a `long` and manually unpacking and comparing the exponent and mantissa using integer operations.